# Kotlin Flow Control - readln()!!.toInt()

Tags: kotlin

I started learning Kotlin a few days ago and I don't really understand why in this case you should use readln()!!.toInt(), from where the number is taken and to which "line" it refers.

fun main(args: Array) {

```
var number: Int
var sum = 0

for (i in 1..6) {
    print("Enter an integer: ")
    number = readln()!!.toInt()
```

It would be extremely helpful if someone could explain that.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readline()` (not `readln()`) returns a line from the standard input stream, or null if the input stream has been redirected to a file and EOF (end of file) is reached. Its return type is `String?` meaning it could either be a `String`, or it could be null.

`!!` is "We are sure this will never be null; force this into a non-nullable type." It means you don't have to deal with the condition where the object you're working with is null.

In this case, the `!!` is saying "We're sure that system input hasn't been redirected to a file (or if it has, that EOF hasn't been reached); wait for the user to input something."

It looks like someone has mixed up `readline()` and `readln()` (which I did when I first answered this question) - @Tenfour04 is right; there's no need to use `!!` with `readln`. It does the same thing, except it throws an exception if EOF is encountered.

Comment: `!!` is pointless with `readln` since it returns non-nullable String. It’s `readLine` that returns nullable.

Comment: You're right! I have edited the answer; hopefully appropriately. Thank you.